# how to get a list of weekdays by giving a date as input in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Say I'm entering a date like DateTime.Now or Date.Now so My required output will be a list of dates in that entered date's week.

**input = 1/1/2018**

**output needed as = {1/1/2018,2/1/2018,3/1/2018,4/1/2018,5/1/2018,6/1/2018,7/1/2018}**

```
 Dim today As Date = CDate(req.SelectedDate)
                                              Dim currentDayOfWeek As Integer = CInt(today.DayOfWeek)
                                              Dim sunday As DateTime = today.AddDays(-currentDayOfWeek)
                                              Dim monday As DateTime = sunday.AddDays(1)
                                              If currentDayOfWeek = 0 Then
                                                  monday = monday.AddDays(-7)
                                              End If
                                              Dim dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).[Select](Function(days) sunday.AddDays(days)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
public static DateTime StartOfWeek(DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
{
    int diff = (7 + (dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek)) % 7;
    return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime sow = StartOfWeek(dt, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    DateTime[] allWeekDays = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(d => sow.AddDays(d)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You can get the start of the week from `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek` if you have a culture.